# How can I prevent my timer app from being terminated by iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nstimer, multitasking

I have a timer app, it counts up for an indefinite amount of time (until the user stops the timer). It works much like the default iOS clock stopwatch.

I have read the articles about being a responsible background app. I don't have any UI changes happening and stop the timer when the app goes in the background and resume the timer upon returning to foreground. The app does send a local notification every 30 minutes or so to remind the user to take a break.

Problem: Without fail my app is terminated after a few hours (between 2-6 or so hours) and the current timer and info is lost.

Things I've tried:

-As aforementioned I changed my app to follow the guidelines of being a responsible background app (before I had the timer UI counting up and also the timer running, even while in background). I thought this would solve the problem since my app isn't using up much memory or doing any intensive tasks.

-I also have tried saving out the data of the current timer (to NSUserDefaults) in ApplicationWillTerminate and then restore it on DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions. It doesn't seem to work. It's almost like my app is force quit or something because if ApplicationWillTerminate was being called then it would save the data and restore it upon the app launching again. Mystery.

-Currently I'm saving an NSDate of the start time of the NSTimer on ApplicationDidEnterBackground, invalidating the timer, and starting the timer and restoring the start time upon ApplicationWillEnterForeground. Still no luck.

The thing is this is affecting a very small percentage of my users--so it's not like it's a problem for everyone, which makes it more confusing.  I still want to fix it of course because it's a pretty lame bug--and I've encountered it myself (on an iPhone 5), so it's not necessarily an old iPhone low memory somethingorother problem.

This has really boggled me, I've done my research and also scoured fairly well the stack overflow questions and don't seem to find much of anything to help me.

Any help would be appreciated, feel free to ask more questions or tell me to clarify.

Comment: Why does it matter if the OS kills your app? You can schedule local notifications while the app is running, and the user will still see those. You can save the start time, as you're currently doing. If the user isn't using your app, it doesn't need to be sitting there in the background using space and power.

Comment: Because when the user enters the app I want them to see the time elapsed since they started and when the app gets killed that information is lost. I think the problem is (as Wain pointed out) that ApplicationWillTerminate is not being called--so the info is not saving. I am testing this to make sure though. I still find it odd though that after only a few hours my application is killed, especially since I have nothing happening in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`applicationWillTerminate` is basically never called. It will not be called when your app is in the background and it gets removed from memory. You should expect your app to be removed from memory if it hasn't been used for a while. How long "a while" is depends on what else the device is doing at the time... Best to use `applicationDidEnterBackground:` or `applicationWillResignActive:`.

Comment: Good to know about applicationWillTerminate not being called. The thing is I am saving the data in applicationDidEnterBackground (NSDate of the start time of the timer) and then restore upon ApplicationWillEnterForeground. Still no luck. App still gets killed as if it's a memory intensive application.

Comment: You have to expect it to get 'killed' (removed from memory). It shouldn't make a difference to the operation when it's brought back if you are saving and restoring correctly.

Comment: so when you say "saving and restoring correctly" do you mean saving out to NSUserDefaults (like I tried) and restoring the values upon ApplicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions? Or do you mean State Preservation?

Comment: And just to clarify, you're saying save out the info on ApplicationDidEnterBackground (instead of WillTerminate, because it's not getting called when my app is pulled from memory) and that way I'm good to go even if the app is removed from memory. Correct?

Comment: Yes, use `applicationWillResignActive` (not `applicationWillTerminate`). Restore in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`. `NSUserDefaults` is fine.

Comment: Ah ok, this makes sense. I'm testing currently and will accept your answer when I see this work. I see no reason why it wouldn't. Is there any way to manually test/simulate your app being removed from memory?

Comment: Run in the simulator from Xcode, hit the home button and then stop in Xcode.

Comment: From the current docs on `applicationWillTerminate` (emphasis mine): "For apps that support background execution, this method is generally not called when the user quits the app because the app simply moves to the background (...). However, this method _may be called in situations where the app is running in the background (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason._"
 - http://goo.gl/h1BWLl Doesn't that imply that it WILL get called when an app in the background is removed from memory? Has the behavior changed since this answer was posted? Are the docs wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When your app goes into the background, record your timer's elapsed time (eg: in NSUserDefaults or however you prefer).  Also record the current time.  When the app comes back into the foreground, look at the two values you recorded and update the elapsed time accordingly, ie:

elapsedTime = savedElapsedTime + (currentTime - timeWentIntoBackground)

There's really no reason your app needs to remain active in the background burning the user's battery just to keep track of seconds ticking by.

Also, don't rely on applicationWillTerminate.  Use applicationWillEnterBackground.

Comment: So I actually am doing exactly that and my app still gets killed after a few hours. I have no tasks being performed (other than those UILocalNotifications being sent) in the background.